# How to create own log4j log level with convinient method

Tags: java, logging, log4j

With growing projects we made new agreements in terms of logging different scenarios within these projects, because we usually tend to forget to delete tons of disrubting logger calls  which where used for hunting bugs in production code (we even created a coffee bug, where everyone has to pay 20c for each undesired logger without success :/). So what I would love to have is a special log level for [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) which we can use for debug purposes only.

Currently there are these loggers:

```
DEBUG
INFO
WARN
ERROR
FATAL
```

warn, error and fatal are speaking for themselves but I would love to add another category somewhere before DEBUG, because INFO we want to use for general logging of application in production mode and DEBUG gives detail Information about project states, which aren`t necessarly of use in production mode.

Next to DEBUG I would appreciate having a special logger, like for example USER (or simular), for temporary included loggers, which where used for example for bug hunting, or whatever, which can be when found in code be deleted at every time, without hesitation.

I stumbled over this useful [article](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/200712.mbox/%3C14203484.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) to create an own custom level, but I hate, that I have to add the log level at every log I want to add for debug purposes:

```
logger.log(MyLevel.DISASTER, "i am a disaster");
```

So I wondered if there is any way to simply this to gain a new method like

```
logger.disaster( "i am a disaster" );
```

for example with writing a fassade for Logger.class. Unfortunatly I am not sure, about logger Initialization and - Creation for delegation to the logger, so I wondered, if anyone might have any idea to simply this.I know with coding templates I can generate the level easily, but it just doesnt read well.

Comment: a decorator/wrapper for the logger may be which internally will call add the label? The logger initialization takes the same steps as until now. All you do is add a class YourLogger that will call the logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's just me but wouldn't :

```
 class DisasterLogger{
      private static final Log logger = Logger.getLogger(DisasterLogger.class); //or any other way you provide the logger
      public void log(String message){
           logger.log(MyLevel.DISASTER, message);
      }
 }
```

simply work?

Comment: The "source" of _all_ logs made through this would then be DisasterLogger and not the place, where the message is actually logged from. As far as I remember.

Comment: This might be also delegatable when creating DisasterLogger. Sounds like an idea to me on how to solve this issue. In terms of performance, it shouldnt be much of a problem in wrapping that logger in my own logger object, should it? Or is it a problem, creating an own instance for every class?

Comment: @ymene you can make them static and they will be created when the class is loaded/application starts. Even if they are not static, creating objects in Java is usually very cheap, especially one like this.

Comment: I created a small example. Is that exactly how you had it in mind, or any other suggestions, comments?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Implementation after very helpful opinions to this topic from Eugene and Fildor:

```
public class IspLogger
{
  private final Logger logger;

  private IspLogger( String clazzName )
  {
    logger = Logger.getLogger( clazzName );
  }

  public static IspLogger getLogger( Class<?> clazz )
  {
    return new IspLogger( clazz.getName() );
  }

  public void info( Object message )
  {
    logger.log( IspLogger.class.getCanonicalName(), Level.INFO, message, null );
  }

  public void info( Object message, Throwable t )
  {
    logger.log( IspLogger.class.getCanonicalName(), Level.INFO, message, t);
  }

  public void dev( Object message )
  {
    logger.log( IspLogger.class.getCanonicalName(), IspDebugLevel.ISP_DEBUG, message, null );
  }

  public void dev( Object message, Throwable t )
  {
    logger.log( IspLogger.class.getCanonicalName(), IspDebugLevel.ISP_DEBUG, message, t);
  }

  public void debug( Object message )
  {
    logger.log( IspLogger.class.getCanonicalName(), Level.DEBUG, message, null );
  }

  ...
}


class IspDebugLevel extends Level
{
  public static final IspDebugLevel ISP_DEBUG = new IspDebugLevel( 20000, "DEV", 0 );/20000 is equal to INFO.

  public IspDebugLevel( int level, String levelStr, int syslogEquivalent )
  {
    super( level, levelStr, syslogEquivalent );
  }

  public static IspDebugLevel toLevel( int val, Level defaultLevel )
  {
    return ISP_DEBUG;
  }

  public static IspDebugLevel toLevel( String sArg, Level defaultLevel )
  {
    return ISP_DEBUG;
  }
}


public class LoggerTest
{
  private static final IspLogger logger = IspLogger.getLogger( LoggerTest.class );

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    logger.dev( "Hello World" );
  }
}
```